# Basic feasible solutions with a continuum of variables

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, linear-programming

Consider the following linear program, where $x$ is a vector of $n$ variables, $c$ is a constant vector of size $n$, $A$ is an $m\times n$ matrix, and $b$ is a constant vector of size $m$:

$$
\text{maximize}~~ c\cdot x
\\
\text{subject to}~~ Ax = b
\\
~~~~x \geq 0
$$

It is known that, if this problem has an optimal solution, then it has an optimal *basic feasible* solution, in which at most $m$ variables have nonzero values.

My question: does this also hold when there is a continuum of variables?
Specifically, suppose $f(x)$ is an unknown real function on $[0,1]$, $c(x)$ is a constant function on $[0,1]$, $A(x)$ is a function on $[0,1]$ that returns an $m$-sized vector, and $b$ is a constant vector of size $m$. We want to solve the following problem on $f$:

$$
\text{maximize}~~ \int_{0}^1 c(x) f(x) dx
\\
\text{subject to}~~ \int_{0}^1 A(x) f(x) dx = b
\\
~~~~f(x) \geq 0 ~~ \text{for all} ~~ x\in[0,1]
$$

Suppose there is a function $f$ that is an optimal solution to this problem. Does this problem have an optimal solution in which $f$ has a nonzero value in at most $m$ points?

Comment: Try googling  separated continuous linear program , and look at "Basic solutions and a ‘simplex’ method for a class of continuous linear programs" https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/BFb0006584 ("It can be shown that if there is an optimal solution to an SCLP, then there is a basic optimal solution") and https://www.researchgate.net/publication/316960364_A_simplex-type_algorithm_for_continuous_linear_programs_with_constant_coefficients , among many others to get you going in the right direction.